# using hidden applet in zk

Tags: java, javascript, applet, zk

My task is using hidden signed applet which support cryptography functions. Applet has to be loaded dynamically.

I try to use this example: (no links, just open first google search result from Oracle website) "invoking Applet Methods From JavaScript". The problem is when the applet is loaded and deployed with "deployJava.js" ZK window is disappearing.

My code is:

```
 function loadScript(url, callback)
 {
      // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = url;

      // Then bind the event to the callback function.
      // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
      script.onreadystatechange = callback;
      script.onload = callback;

      // Fire the loading
      head.appendChild(script);
      callback();
 }

 function startApplet() {
      var invokeApplet = function () {
      var attributes = { id:'cryptoApplet', code:'CryptoApplet',  width:1, height:1} ;
      var parameters = { jar: 'clientcrypto.jar'} ;
      deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
      };
      loadScript("/js/deployJava.js", invokeApplet);
 }
```

Comment: I can't see the java in this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Good luck on getting a hidden applet to work after the recent security updates, and with most browsers now disabling applets until you 'Click the space' it will be assigned!

Comment: Depending on what your cryptographic needs are, you may find a javascript alternative.

Comment: Oh, the question is not what I should use for cryptographic.
We are tested applets with new security updates and it works fine with signed applets and some changes in java.policy configuration.
We have to use applets because we use CSP which certified in Russia.

And the main question is how to dynamically load java applet in ZK application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because deployJava.js use "document.write(applet tag)" to add an applet.
I add div component to the page which has width="1", height="1", and rewrite deployJava.js to append applet in that div. And it's worked.